# Insert a massive number of records into database automatically

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to insert a massive number of records such as audio records or images from a folder to mysql database automatically instead of manually ( one by one)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have to do those INSERTs one at a time.  That's how databases work.  Script it and commit in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create your own script or managing the records in arrays (The arrays should be according to your database table) then on those arrays you can loop through and insert all the records.